# Are there smooth functions with countable supports?

Tags: analysis

Does there exist a smooth differentiable function $f: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ whose support $cl \{x \in \mathbb R: f(x) \neq 0 \}$ is a countable set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that if $f$ is not the zero function then $f(x)\ne 0$ on a nonempty open set, which therefore contains an interval $(a,b)$ with $a<b$, which is of course uncountable.